# Geometric/Shape Recognition ( Odd Shape )

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I would like to do some odd geometric/odd shape recognition. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's what I have so far:

1. Convert RGB image to Monochrome.
2. [Otsu Threshold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method)
3. [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

For geometric information, you could do a [raster to vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28image_tracing%29) conversion to convert your image into coordinated vectors (lines and points) and [finite element analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) to look for known shapes.  Not easy but libraries should be available for both.

**Edit:**  Note that there are sometimes easier practical solutions, but they depend on the image and types of errors.  For example, removing perspective, identifying a 3d object from a 2d image, significance of colour, etc...  You often see registration markers added to the real world object to overcome 
 this and allow much easier identification.  Looking up articles on [feature extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) techniques might help.